# Obtener variables formulario cuando submit y pasarlas a un php

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

me gustaria saber como obtener los valores input de un formulario.
Muestro los valores actuales extraidos de la base de datos mediante un echo y la intención es poder cambiarlas.

El código (editarproyectos.php) seria:

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' />
    <tr>
        <td>Titulo</td>
        <td><input type='text' id="titulo" name='titulo' class='form-control' 
            value='<?php echo $tit_proyecto ?>' ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='fecha' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $fech_proyecto; ?>' ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Texto 1</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control" name='text1' rows="2"><?php echo $texto1_proyecto; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Texto 2</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control" name='text1' rows="4"><?php echo $texto2_proyecto; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update" id="btn-update">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Guardar cambios
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Cuando clickeo en submit, me deriva al archivo crud2.js (el que está abajo) pero no consigo que me envie nada a "editar_proyectos_update.php".

```
$.post("editar_proyectos_update.php", $(this).serialize())
    .done(function(data){
        $("#dis").fadeOut();
        $("#dis").fadeIn('slow', function(){
             $("#dis").html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>');
             $("#emp-UpdateForm_Proyectos")[0].reset();
             $("body").fadeOut('slow', function()
             {
                $("body").fadeOut('slow');
                window.location.href="login-register/index.php";
             });                 
         });    
    });
```

Comment: Juan Luis eso se hace con Ajax. Aquí hay muchas preguntas con respuestas que explican todo el proceso. Si buscas en la etiqueta Ajax encontrarás más de una. No te puedo poner algunos enlaces porque ahora estoy desde el móvil. Saludos.

Comment: Si, como dices, pero el código que extraí y ando modificando, trae el .js que acabo de añadir, y me gustaria saber el funcionamiento del mismo, y probar este estilo de POST y no usar el mismo del otro post que me respondiste hace dos dias, y me gustaria saber el funcionamiento de este tipo.

Comment: En `editar_proyectos_update.php` tienes que recibir los datos que se envían en el post, procesarlos y devolver una respuesta que será mostrada desde el `done`. En realidad `$.post` funciona como `$.ajax`. No sé si el problema esté en el tratamiento de los datos o si no está funcionando el código, porque no se ejecuta ese bloque al hacer clic en enviar . Pon un `alert` dentro del post para comprobarlo.

Comment: Con la respuesta de @EduardoSantillan podrás lograrlo, aunque no estoy de acuerdo con él en algunas cosas, pero se lo diré en comentario en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas hacer es enviar tu formulario de forma asíncrona, entonces te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente:

Primero, debes tener en la cabecera de tu página, donde está el formulario, el siguiente script. Este es el que te permitirá usar las funciones de ajax.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En tu Archivo JS debes agregar lo siguiente. Este se encargará de aplicar el submit a tu formulario

```
$(function(){
$("#emp-UpdateForm_Proyectos").on("submit", function(e){ //Ejecutas la acción submit de tu formulario
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("emp-UpdateForm_Proyectos")); //Mediante el formData llamarás a las variables del formulario (inputs)
    formData.append("dato", "valor");
    //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "editar_proyectos_update.php", //url destino
        type: "post", //tipo de envío, post/get
        dataType: "html",
        data: formData, //variables (inputs)
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
    .done(function(result){ //Aquí puedes imprimir algún mensaje de confirmación mediante algún echo.
        alert(result);
    });
});
});
```

En tu archivo PHP que recibirá los datos del formulario 'editar_proyectos_update.php', puedes llamar a las variables mediante $_POST["nombre_variable"], tal como lo haces cuando envías el formulario de manera síncrona:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST["titulo"]) && isset($_POST["fecha"]) && isset($_POST["text1"])) { //Aquí validamos si existe la variable (yo solo coloqué tres parámetros de tu formulario).
      $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
      $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
      $text1 = $_POST["text1"]; 
   }
?>
```

**NOTA: En tu formulario solamente es necesario tener el 'id', no necesitas tener el 'action' ni el 'method'**

```
form id='emp-UpdateForm_Proyectos'>
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices y bien explicado, aunque difiero en algunas cosas: es mejor tener el `action` y el `method` en el formulario. Luego en JS recuperas ese atributo usando `this`. Eso permite escribir un código más genérico, adaptado a cualquier formulario. Además puedes usar esta variable: `var f = $(this);` ya para todo: `var formData = new FormData(f);`   .... `$.ajax({
        url: f.prop("action"), 
        method: f.prop("method"), ` o sea lees las propiedades `action` y `method` del elemento. Por cierto, `type`  era para versiones muy antigua de jQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Lo escribí así en la respuesta porque así me ha funcionado. Pero debo tomarlo en cuenta también.

Comment: @EduardoSantillán muchas gracias, efectivamente funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano como siempre, impecable con sus respuestas. Modificaré los detalles que comentas.

Comment: Una pregunta extra, he buscado pero no he encontrado lo siguiente:
En el formulario de arriba, querria añadir un boton "Examinar" para alojar una imagen en la carpeta /img. 
Por ello, se subiria al servidor la imagen, pero no quiero añadirla al mysql, sino solamente cambiar la ruta de la imagen a a editar.

Comment: @JuanLuisMirasMoreno el inicio del comentario lo dice todo: *Una pregunta extra ...* Precisamente, esa duda o problema no se puede mezclar con esta (aunque sea la misma aplicación), porque es otro problema y por tanto debe ser planteado en **otra pregunta**. El formato de Stackoverflow así lo exige y así debe ser porque el sitio ha sido pensado para mostrar ayudas a problemas concretos problema por problema y que esa ayuda sirva a futuros usuarios. Pero antes de plantear la pregunta busca en el sitio si ya no existe una así o parecida.

Comment: @JuanLuisMirasMoreno Qué bueno que te funcionó, brother.

Comment: @A.Cedano no lo sabia. Busqué por el foro y no encontré ninguna solución (al menos yo no la encontré, muchas decias que no se podia hacer por seguridad).
Crearé otro post para ello.

Comment: @EduardoSantillán Gracias!!

Comment: La pregunta extra que realicé esta en el siguiente post:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178591/a%c3%b1adir-bot%c3%b3n-examinar-a-formulario-y-a%c3%b1adir-imagen-mediante-cambio-de-ruta